# /system/xbin/custom-command cannot be found

Tags: shell, terminal

Originally I copied a shell command  file to `/system/xbin/` as custom-command and it worked, meaning when I am in terminal emulator, I could type

`custom-command`

and it runs. What I did was simply copying the sh file to `/system/xbin/` after removing the `.sh` extension. Now after I restart my phone, I re-enter the command and it fails to run, instead I receive "sh: /system/xbin/custom-command: No such file or directory" message in the terminal...

Comment: Did you make the file executable using `chmod` and can others (not root that is) read that file?

Comment: @Firelord yes, with chmod 777